# converting uint256 to string

Tags: string, uint256

Any idea for the simplest way to add "degrees" variable into the string like below?
Looking for getString to return "today is 40 degrees outside".

```
 pragma solidity ^0.5.3;

        uint public degrees= 40;

        function getString() public view returns(string memory){
                string memory a = "today is ";
                string memory b = degrees;
                string memory c = "degrees outside";
                string memory sentence = string(abi.encodePacked(a, b, c));
                return sentence;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

oraclize helped

```
 pragma solidity ^0.5.3;

        uint public degrees= 40;

        function getString() public view returns(string memory){
                string memory a = "today is ";
                string memory b = uint2str(degrees);
                string memory c = "degrees outside";
                string memory sentence = string(abi.encodePacked(a, b, c));
                return sentence;
        }
```